# What does bind to interface mean in Salt?

Tags: saltstack

In the SaltStack master configuration there is the `interface` option: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html

It specifies the "The local interface to bind to". What does that mean? I've looked everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The doc is just referring to an attached network interface, probably an ethernet port in your case; it looks like the default is already 0.0.0.0 which is a wildcard for "all" or "every" in this context.  If you have more than one NIC on the machine and you don't want to bind Salt to every interface change this to the NIC's IP.  Otherwise it should work fine out of the box as is.